# failing to insert first user into Rails/devise user table

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble seeding my users table.

(rails 3.2.6, jruby 1.6.7.2, devise 2.1.2)

It's a pretty generic User table, generated by "rails generate devise User", plus the modifications described by [this howto page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) so that users can login with username instead of email address.

`rails db:seed` is not giving any indication of error, nor is the log.  When I use sqlite console to confirm, the table is empty.  **Yes, it's using development environment.  I've double and triple-checked this.**

When I use `rails console` and enter the creation command, I get this:

```
1178 ~/dev/proj$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
jruby-1.6.7.2 :001 > User.create( 
jruby-1.6.7.2 :002 >       :username             => 'admin',
jruby-1.6.7.2 :003 >       :email                => 'admin@fake.com', 
jruby-1.6.7.2 :004 >       :password             => 'admin',
jruby-1.6.7.2 :005 >       :password_confirmation => 'admin', 
jruby-1.6.7.2 :006 >     )
    User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'admin@x.com' LIMIT 1
    => #<User id: nil, email: "admin@fake.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$SMz0xdF.BkPV.4IX4TZ6Zu9WbQEk6kvap7mSGfwA7cLe...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, username: "admin">
```

I'm not sure why it says the user exists, because the table was and is still empty, as shown here:

```
jruby-1.6.7.2 :013 > User.all
    User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
=> []
```

It could be that a validation function is malfunctioning.  The only one I can find in my source is the `find_first_by_auth_conditions` one that I copied (as directed) out of the aforementioned-howto page, but that doesn't look to me like it could be causing this.

I'd appreciate any help.  What's preventing me from creating this user?

**Update:** If I use the following, it works:

```
u = User.new(...)
u.save(:validate=>false)
```

So this means that my validation is failing somewhere.  Unfortunately, I haven't coded any validation aside from the one method I mentioned earlier.  How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ugh.  It turns out that this user's password was too short.

Looks like the "User Exists" message is actually quite misleading.  It gives you the same thing if you create a user where password != confirmation.

Created an issue on the devise project to see if this can be improved.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1985

**Edit:** And that issue was answered, and I see that I just didn't know how to read the error messages.

Comment: Is there a way to change this password length constraint .. ?

Comment: Oh got the solution my bad had to configure it in devise.rb